# how to split numeric values by comma in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have numeric values in my column

[image]

I want this values should look like

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `to_char()` [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

```
select to_char(the_column, '9,99,999') as nr
from your_table
```